# Getting substrings from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string like this:

```
String ColorCodes = "colorcodes:#FFOOFF,#OOACOF,#EEAAAA"
```

I want to get the three color codes in the above string into three different strings, like this:

```
String ColorOne = "#FFOOFF"
String ColorTwo = "#OOACOF"
String ColorThree = "#EEAAAA"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Split on `:` then second part split on `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring`and `split`:

```
    String[] colors = colorCodes.substring(colorCodes.indexOf(":") + 1).split(",");
            
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(colors));
```

**Output**

```
[#FFOOFF, #OOACOF, #EEAAAA]
```